# Find the starting node such that will get shortest path by passing through specific nodes

Tags: graph, dijkstra

I have an undirected graph with at most 10 000 nodes and 50 000 edges . I need to find the node in which i should start such that passing through some mustpass nodes the distance will be the shortest.

I was thinking at applying Dijkstra between the nodes of the graph , but i don't know how to select the best starting node.

The mustpass nodes may be visited in any order.

Comment: So your input is a G=(V,E), a node P (the must pass node), and a final node F. You want to find a node S, such that ∂(S,P) + ∂(P,F) is minimal? If this is the case, then select S=P and use a shortest path algorithm to find ∂(P,F). That gives you 0 + ∂(P,F).

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a version of the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) which is NP-Hard so no simple and quick solution exist for it.

you could try to find sub-optimal solutions using heuristics and aproximation algorithms, also, since you only need to visit a subset of the nodes, you could limit your search to those.